# Gradle: where is Project's evaluate() method documented?

Tags: gradle

Where is the `evaluate()` method of `org.gradle.api.Project`documented in the Gradle documentation?

I see that it is used in the unit tests of a [plugin](https://github.com/Alex-Vol/gradle-native-artifacts-plugin/blob/master/src/test/groovy/me/sgeb/gradle/nativeartifacts/NativeComponentTest.groovy) that I am interested in trying to port to v3.x:

```
def project
// ...
project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
// ...
project.evaluate()
```

I cannot find `evaluate()` in the [DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) or [API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) documentation.  `ProjectBuilder`'s `build()` method returns a Project, according to the [documentation here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testfixtures/ProjectBuilder.html).  Am I looking in the wrong place, or is this a dynamic method that is added somewhere else?

Comment: The `evaluate()` is part of the internal APIs when the tasks are created.

Comment: Thanks - I see the plugin is riddled with calls to internal methods.  Is the internal API documentation online, by any chance please?

Comment: To be honest it is a quiet pain to find out how gradle works internally. I gave up and tried another way.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate is still available if you cast your `Project` var to `DefaultProject`

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject

val project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
(project as DefaultProject).evaluate()
```

Taken from: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/unit-test-plugins-afterevaulate/37437

Comment:  5 years later, I hope you've found closure.